# gprof 's "e" and "f" options can't work

Tags: linux, gprof

I want to use `gprof` to analyse my program. my code is as below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int func1(){
   int r = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
       r+=1;
   return 0;
}        
int func(){
   int r = 0;
   for(int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
       r+=2;
  return 0;
}
int main(){
  int a0, a1;
  a0 = func();
  a1 = func1();
  printf("%d," a0+a1);
  return 0;
}
```

And I use `g++ main.cpp -o test -pg` to compile my testbed. Then run it `./test` to generate `gmon.out` file.
And I use `gprof -f func ./test` and `gprof -e func ./test` . **It still can  generate both func() and func1() informations**

**PS:**   **Here is the version infos on my computer**
GNU gprof (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22.90.20120924
Based on BSD gprof, copyright 1983 Regents of the University of California.

Comment: Works correctly for me. The corresponding function only/does not show up in the *call graph* section (both show up in the general "flat profile" section). -f and -e relate to the call graph section according to the man page.

Comment: Going through the man page for gprof, its mentioned that the options -e and -f a re deprecated. This means you are using the latest release of GPROF. Refer** http://linux.die.net/man/1/gprof **for more details

Comment: This program will finish before a photon from the window can cross a room, so it probably won't get any samples.

Comment: @stantosh : These options are deprecated. so which options can I use instead of

Comment: Will be watching this, just got introduced to `gprof` recently and it seems like an interesting tool to learn, to say the least.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey : I added a loop in each function. And it still the same